# imap function is not working for me with PHP

Tags: php, imap

I try to access my gmail account with PHP, but I get an error message in line 2. IMAP is enabled in Gmail, while POP is not enabled.

```
$mbox = imap_open("{imap.gmail.com:993/ssl}", "email@gmail.com", "password");

echo "<h1>Mailboxes</h1>\n";
$folders = imap_listmailbox($mbox, "{imap.gmail.com:993}", "*");

if ($folders == false) {
    echo "Call failed<br />\n";
}
else {
    foreach ($folders as $val) {
        echo $val . "<br />\n";
    }
}

echo "<h1>Headers in INBOX</h1>\n";
$headers = imap_headers($mbox);

if ($headers == false) {
    echo "Call failed<br />\n";
}
else {
    foreach ($headers as $val) {
        echo $val . "<br />\n";
    }
}

imap_close($mbox);
```

Comment: i get error: Fatal error: Call to undefined function imap_open() in C:\wamp\www\Test\gmail.php on line 2

Comment: Which php version are you using?

Comment: PHP version 5.3.5   and i forgot to tell i use wampserver

Answer (score 2):

You need to enable imap in your `php.ini`.

> I used the wamp menu to edit the php.ini. I enabled the php_imap.dll.

-> http://www.wampserver.com/phorum/read.php?2,23447,printview,page=1

Comment: OK the line in php_ini is ;extension=php_imap.dll do i have to remove the comma?

Comment: now i get this error Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\wamp\www\Test\gmail.php on line 16

Comment: @user983687: I'm sorry but stackoverflow is not the right platform for such questions - besides have you checked the search function? Or Google? [imap_open undefined](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+imap_open+undefined&submit=search), [Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Maximum+execution+time+of+30+seconds+exceeded).

Comment: You should post the answer anyways.

Comment: i use this line init_set('max_execution_time', 123456);

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution:

I am running `Windows 7 64bit` environment with `WAMP` server, it has two `php.ini` files:

```
1] C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.2.22\bin
   Enable php_imap.dll extension by removing ; at beginning of string

2] C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.13
   Enable php_imap.dll extension by removing ; at beginning of string
```

And it works now !

Comment: Just to specify that thoses two php.ini have a purpose. The one in the apache*/bin dir is used by apache when serving php pages via http. The other one is used by php when running a php script in cli mode (in that case, apache is not used)